# Android - blocking certain applications

Tags: android, android-activity, block

I want that the user using my app will be able to block some applications such as the Gmail app, web browser or any other one chosen by him. This means, that whenever the selected app is launched, it will be automatically killed by my app.

How is this achievable? Thanks :D

Comment: It depends on how bad you need this. Consume all phone memory, create files and create threads. The user will probably kill it!

Comment: I want to kill specific apps, not all of them

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/freetaskmanager/source/browse/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a broadcaste receiver, and these are implicit intent, so on matching those intent you can kill them.

Comment: There is nothing correct about this answer. Nothing is broadcast when applications start and stop. And, you cannot kill them in any case once they are in the foreground.

Comment: OK, but how application like AppLock works, they have a main password for every application and if the password is correct then its only lauched other wise cancelled. If i am wrong please suggest whether its possible or not.

Comment: @Progammer: I am not saying that it is not possible. I am saying that your answer is wrong.

Comment: Ok, but could you suggest me right answer, may be it might be usefull for me aswell then.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible because there are Apps [like](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=autokiller.task.killer.mt&hl=de) and they kill task and now you shoud do somthing like that but kill them with a Service